# Expandable Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to create expandable buttons exactly like the ones near the bottom of this site (http://mastermechanic.ca/services.php), but I've been having trouble figuring it out. I'm a beginner in JavaScript, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually that is not "button", it is designed like button.  check things here https://api.jquery.com/slideDown

Comment: probably best to show us whatever code you already have

Answer (score 0):

HTML:
`<button id="lol">Some long text</button>`

CSS: `#lol {color: white; font-size: 2em; background: yellow; border: 5px solid orange; border-radius: 3px; padding: 10px 20px}`

Answer (score 0):

try defining width for button...

see example [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7S6mR/)

```
#lol {color: white; font-size: 2em; background: yellow; border: 5px solid orange; border-radius: 3px; padding: 10px 20px; width: 50%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made the CSS you may need to have the exact button in the link below. I hope it helps. Cheer.

CSS:

```
.big {
  background: #fb7303;
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  border: 5px solid #ffa500;
  border-radius:10px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
 <button class="big">Schedule <br>Maintenance</button>
```

Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/dHq74/3/

Answer (score 0):

I didn't create a very detailed example, but this should set you on the right track. You can play around with it from here.

They use a combination of Jquery & Css, when the user clicks on the "Button" it adds the class "fullheight", and when the click it again, it adds a class "smallheight"

```
$( "#reveal-container" ).toggleClass("smallheight");
$( "#reveal-container" ).toggleClass("fullheight");
```

I **DIDNT** do this. Buy maybe you can still benefit from my example:

I just created a container DIV like they did, then use Jquery to slide it open and closed:

**jQuery**

```
 $(".button").click(function () {
        $button = $(this);
        $content = $button.next(); 
        $content.slideToggle(500, function () {   
         });

    });
```

See  [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/1590/) for full example .

Hope this helps you. :)